# Gameresearch / Understanding generation of player id

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hash, analytics

I've collected data based on game statistics.

I can't figure out what might be the function behind the generation of player ids. I think its based on the registration time of the user/player.

Here is a sample of player ids, sorted:

```
59f39d7046b16841df49bb76
59f39d7046b16841e06b1b47
59f39d7102153a762c796c35
59f39d7202153a762c796d09
59f39d7246b168428d63c984
59f39d73144ead375c438735
59f39d73144ead375e50c1b8
59f39d7346b16841e26556e6
59f39d7388a45020da797776
59f39d7388a450215c320555
59f39d7388a45021a905bf17
59f39d74144ead375c43880d
59f39d7488a45020d7701094
59f39d7502153a758a3c362b
59f39d7502153a759859c5f9
59f39d75144ead37a75db0a4
59f39d7546b16841df49bd14
59f39d7546b16841e06b1c21
59f39d7546b16841e26557bf
59f39d7546b168424d2fef07
59f39d7588a45021a905bfc7
59f39d7588a45026b77d1ced
59f39d7602153a758b1b7518
59f39d7602153a762c796dea
```

A longer sample is available here: http://pastebin.com/raw/iFy5tc5k

The first 8 bytes are the current unix time in hex. Like right now its 5A4AEC0A. I am wondering about the last 16.

They are increasing over time. Hex notation.

It is not a usual hash because it would not increase like this.

I'd be happy for suggestions. A heads up into the right direction will be sufficient. I want to understand it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about reverse engineering.

Comment: You're wrong buddy, but i can understand your comment. I dont want todo RE any game code or stuff, instead i just want to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: I consider it reverse engineering because you have the output of some algorithm without any details about how that output is generated and you're looking for help in recreating the algorithm. I also don't think there's enough information here for this to be answered (in a useful manner) - you'd typically need to supply a substantial portion of the **input** for each output as well - with no input it's more just creating a random function that matching the pattern with any amount of guesses to fill in the blanks. One can spot things like repeating 46b1684's, but one can't be sure what it means.

Answer (score 0):

This might be in the same format MongoDB uses for its unique IDs. That is a also a 12-byte ID formed using a 4-byte UNIX timestamp, a machine identifier, a process identifier, and a per-process counter with a randomized starting value. I have sorted the data by what might be the machine ID and then by the UNIX timestamp and we can see the following:

```
59f39d73 144ead 375c 438735
59f39d73 144ead 375e 50c1b8
59f39d74 144ead 375c 43880d
59f39d75 144ead 37a7 5db0a4

59f39d73 88a450 20da 797776
59f39d73 88a450 215c 320555
59f39d73 88a450 21a9 05bf17
59f39d74 88a450 20d7 701094
59f39d75 88a450 21a9 05bfc7
59f39d75 88a450 26b7 7d1ced

59f39d71 02153a 762c 796c35
59f39d72 02153a 762c 796d09
59f39d75 02153a 758a 3c362b
59f39d75 02153a 7598 59c5f9
59f39d76 02153a 758b 1b7518
59f39d76 02153a 762c 796dea

59f39d70 46b168 41df 49bb76
59f39d70 46b168 41e0 6b1b47
59f39d72 46b168 428d 63c984
59f39d73 46b168 41e2 6556e6
59f39d75 46b168 41df 49bd14
59f39d75 46b168 41e0 6b1c21
59f39d75 46b168 41e2 6557bf
59f39d75 46b168 424d 2fef07
```

First, we notice that the timestamps look like fairly recent UNIX data/time data, so this checks out.

Second, we notice a fair amount of repetition in the second column. This could make sense if we are getting multiple entries per machine; maybe these are servers or something supporting multiple clients, or maybe this is more of a session/login table or something like that.

There is less commonality in the process ID, but we do notice this: within a machine, all the PIDs are fairly close, and across machines they are unrelated. This is what we would expect to be the case if these really were process IDs, so this is looking good.

In the fourth column, you can confirm that whenever the machine and process are the same, later times in the first column mean bigger numbers in the fourth. This is what we'd expect if a counter were being incremented on a per-process basis.

That this data appears to be using the same format as MongoDB unique IDs appears to be consistent. That doesn't mean it is correct.